# xmodmap not running in .profile

Tags: shortcut-keys, .profile

I recently followed this guide to get some keys mapped to my Alt Gr https://medium.com/@retprogramisto/how-to-make-custom-keyboard-map-with-xmodmap-1341a1552d4f

It worked fine, but when it came to getting the command `xmodmap ~/.Xmodmap` to run on startup, I didn't have `.xinitrc` in my home directory, so I put it in my `.profile`.

After a reboot, it didn't run the command (I guess) and my accented characters are not mapped like they should be.

Was it a mistake to put the command in `.profile`? Should I perhaps create `.xinitrc` and put it in there?

Thanks.

```
$ lsb_release -a && uname -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS
Release:    20.04
Codename:   focal
Linux leon 5.11.0-46-generic #51~20.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jan 7 06:51:40 UTC 2022 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The keyboard in your user session may not have been initialized yet when `.profile` is being run when you log in.

Xmodmap is not anymore the ideal way to change keyboard layouts. For example, when switching keyboard layouts, it will need to be reloaded each time. Unfortunately, editing [`kbd` files directly](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Custom%20keyboard%20layout%20definitions?action=show&redirect=Howto%3A%20Custom%20keyboard%20layout%20definitions) is complicated and not applicable on a per user basis.

Formally, a file `.Xmodmap` would automatically be sourced when logging in. This is [not anymore so since Gnome 3.8](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=674874). `.xinitrc`, on the other hand, is relevant only if you use `startx` rather than a login manager to load your session.

Instead you can automatically run the command on login using an autostart launcher: create a .desktop launcher in your autostart directory with the command

```
gedit ~/.config/autostart/xmodmap.desktop
```

and enter following code:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Xmodmap
Exec=xmodmap /home/<yourlogin/.Xmodmap
Terminal=false
Type=Application
X-GNOME-Autostart-Delay=1
X-GNOME-Autostart-enabled=true
```

Without delay, the activation may not systematically succeed. `X-GNOME-Autostart-Delay=1` introduces a delay of one second before running the command.

Comment: Thanks. It's a bit hacky, but it worked :)